# Differential of Matrix Inverse

Tags: real-analysis, linear-algebra, derivatives

I am trying to solve the following problem:
$$ G: \; GL(n,\textbf{R}) \to GL(n,\textbf{R}), \quad A \mapsto A^{-1}$$
Find the total derivative $dG(A)$.

The domain and range of $G$ are isomorphic to $$\textbf{R}^{n^2} \to \textbf{R}^{n^2},$$ i.e. $dG(A)\in \text{Mat}(n^2\times n^2,\textbf{R}$), and every element in that matrix is simply an entry of $A^{-1}$ partially differentiated to an element of $A$. I'm having trouble finding these partial derivatives.

Consider a similar problem: 
$$F: \text{Mat}(n\times n,\textbf{R})\times \text{Mat}(n\times n,\textbf{R}) \to \text{Mat}(n\times n,\textbf{R}), \quad (A,B) \mapsto A\cdot B$$
Here we have a simple formula for each entry of $A\cdot B$, which is 
$$(A\cdot B)_{i,j} = \sum_{k=1}^{n}a_{i,k}\cdot b_{k,j}$$ and thus finding the partial derivatives is simple (you end up giving a parametric solution for $dF(A,B)$, with $dF(A,B)\in \text{Mat}(n^2\times 2n^2,\textbf{R})$).

Another example is the determinant function. Again, it is simple here, as e.g. the Leibniz formula gives us an explicit formula for each entry.

I was unable to find such a formula for $A^{-1}$, and was wondering if anyone had some ideas on how to tackle this problem.

Answer (score 1):

I was in a dillema, since this question was answered [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1697307/finding-the-second-derivative-of-fg-rightarrow-l-mathbbrn-mathbbrn/1697367#1697367). But as it is not a duplicate per se, I'll copy the part of my answer which adresses your question.

\begin{align*}
f(X+H)&=(X+H)^{-1}\\
&=(X(I+X^{-1}H))^{-1}\\
&=(I+X^{-1}H)^{-1}X^{-1}\\
&=(I-(-X^{-1}H))^{-1}X^{-1}\\
&=\left(\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}(-X^{-1}H)^n\right)X^{-1}\\
&=X^{-1}- X^{-1}HX^{-1}+o(H).
\end{align*}

Therefore, $f'_X(\,\cdot\,)=-X^{-1}(\,\cdot\,)X^{-1}$.

Comment: Very elementary remark: in dimension 1, one finds back that the derivative of $1/x$ is $-1/x^2$...